# wpf TreeView binding having multiple TreeViewItemStyle

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, treeview

i'm able to create dinamicaly both RadioButtions and CheckBoxes inside TreeViewItem using this code in Window1.cs initialization:

```
        TreeViewItem parent = createTextInTree("Выпечка", tree);
        createCheckBoxChildren("торт Птичье молоко - 350 звезд", parent);
        createCheckBoxChildren("пироженное Тирамиссу - 25 UAH", parent);
        createCheckBoxChildren("пироженное Тирамиссу - 70 звезд", parent);
        createCheckBoxChildren("тарт Вишня - 35 звезд", parent);


        parent = createTextInTree("Мороженное", tree);
        createRadioButtonsChildren("ванильное - 15 звезд", parent, "grp1");
        createRadioButtonsChildren("шоколадное - 15 звезд", parent, "grp1");
        createRadioButtonsChildren("клубничное - 15 звезд", parent, "grp1");

        parent = createTextInTree("Кофе", tree);
        createRadioButtonsChildren("эспрессо - 30 звезд", parent, "grp2");
        createRadioButtonsChildren("латте - 25 UAH", parent, "grp2");
        createRadioButtonsChildren("латте - 50 звезд", parent, "grp2");
        createRadioButtonsChildren("капучино - 35 звезд", parent, "grp2");
```

There methods are:

```
    private TreeViewItem createTextInTree(string content, TreeView tree)
    {
        TreeViewItem item = new TreeViewItem()
        {
            Header = content
        };
        tree.Items.Add(item);
        return item;
    }

    private TreeViewItem createCheckBoxInTree(string content, TreeView tree)
    {
        TreeViewItem item = new TreeViewItem()
        {
            Header = new CheckBox()
            {
                Content = content
            }
        };
        tree.Items.Add(item);
        return item;
    }

    private void createCheckBoxChildren(string content, TreeViewItem item)
    {
        TreeViewItem child = new TreeViewItem()
        {
            Header = new CheckBox()
            {
                Content = content,
            }
        };
        item.Items.Add(child);
    }


    private void createRadioButtonsChildren(string content, TreeViewItem item, string group)
    {
        TreeViewItem childRadio = new TreeViewItem()
        {
            Header = new RadioButton()
            {
                Content = content,
                GroupName = group,
            }
        };
        item.Items.Add(childRadio);
    }
```

Control now looks like that:
[Control dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bbIL.jpg)

Using example: [TreeView with Checkboxes](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28306/Working-with-Checkboxes-in-the-WPF-TreeView) I was succeded to use bindings in case i have only one model for TreeViewItem, but not in case i have multiple ones.

Here is my current xaml:

> <Window.Resources>
>
>
> <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
>
> </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
>
> ```
>   <Style x:Key="TreeViewItemStyle" TargetType="TreeViewItem">
>     <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True" />
>     <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsInitiallySelected, Mode=OneTime}" >
>     <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.AcceptsReturn" Value="True" />
>     <Setter Property="dw:VirtualToggleButton.IsVirtualToggleButton" Value="True" />
>     <Setter Property="dw:VirtualToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="{Binding IsChecked}" />
>     <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="30"/>
>   </Style>
>         <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeView}">
>             <Style.Resources>
>                 <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="#CBE8F6" />
>                 <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
>                 <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
>             </Style.Resources>
>         </Style>
>         <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
>             <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
>             <Style.Triggers>
>                 <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
>                     <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#26A0DA" />
>                 </Trigger>
>                 <MultiTrigger>
>                     <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
>                         <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
>                         <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="False" />
>                     </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
>                     <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#DADADA" />
>                 </MultiTrigger>
>             </Style.Triggers>
>         </Style>
>
>       <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="RadioButtonItemTemplate" DataType="{x:Type local:FooViewModel2}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children, Mode=OneTime}">
>             <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
>                 <RadioButton Focusable="False" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
>                 <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Name, Mode=OneTime}" Height="30" Margin="8,0" />
>             </StackPanel>
>         </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
>         <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="CheckBoxItemTemplate" DataType="{x:Type local:FooViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children, Mode=OneTime}" >
>     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
>       <!-- These elements are bound to a FooViewModel object. -->
>       <CheckBox Focusable="False" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
>       <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Name, Mode=OneTime}" Height="30" Margin="8,0" />
>     </StackPanel>
>   </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
> </ResourceDictionary>
> ```
>
> </Window.Resources>
> <Window.DataContext>
>
> </Window.DataContext>
>
> ```
> <DockPanel>
>     <TreeView x:Name="tree" Width="450" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TreeViewItemStyle}"  ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneTime}"  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource RadioButtonItemTemplate}" />
>     <StackPanel Background="White">
>         <Button Command="Undo" Content="Uncheck All" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,2" Padding="8,0"/>
>         <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Content="Ok" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,2" Padding="8,0"/>
>         <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" IsCancel="True" IsDefault="True" Content="Отмена" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,2" Padding="8,0"/>
>         <Label Name="lblTotalBonusesTitle" Content="Всего бонусов" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,2" Padding="1,0" />
>         <Label Name="lblTotalBonuses" Content="750" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,2" Padding="1,0" />
>         <Label Name="lblChosenBonusesTitle" Content="Выбрано" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,2" Padding="1,0" />
>         <Label Name="lblChosenBonuses" Content="320" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="DemiBold" Margin="0,2" Padding="1,0" />
>         <Label Name="lblChosenStrTitle" Content="Выбраны" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,2" Padding="1,0" />
>         <Label Name="lblChosenStr" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="DemiBold" Margin="0,2" Padding="1,0" />            
>     </StackPanel>
> </DockPanel>
> ```

Comment: This is not a good idea. How do you build a tree of many items - manually? A lot of repeating code. You should bind the collection of data models to the TreeView and then use DataTemplates and HierarchicalDataTemplates to create the view for this items. You can use a data model for each node type (RadioButton, CheckBox etc.). Doing this in C# does not scale. You should use XAML and templates.

Comment: Only create the tree structure using data models. WPF will then create the actual TreeViewItem containers for you (including all the controls) according to the defined templates.

Comment: It is also more convenient to extend the TreeView class e.g., MultiSelectTreeView, and have it expose a SelectedItems property which you can bind to. This removes the requirement to spend every participating data model a IsSelected property. You would have to traverse the complete tree in order to collect the selected items (or add complex event logic) whereas a SelectedItems property would simplify this filtering and would also improve the perfomance. Additionally, a SelectedItems property would move the complete selection logic from the data models to the MultiSelectTreeView control.

Answer (score 0):

I settled on using a `DataTemplateSelector`.  This is a custom class with a method that returns a `DataTemplate` based on whatever criteria you need.  The custom `DataTemplateSelector` is then assigned to the element: in the case of `ListBox` it is the `ItemTemplateSelector` property.